# Having trouble with the order of items in the legend of a ggplot bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend

My data looks like

```
    language    tone        count   tone_percent    label_pos   pos
1   c           positive    3460    36.16977        18.08488    7
2   c           neutral     2046    21.38825        46.86389    7
3   c           negative    4060    42.44198        78.77901    7
4   c#          positive    3732    41.26949        20.63475    3
5   c#          neutral     1832    20.25876        51.39887    3
6   c#          negative    3479    38.47175        80.76413    3
7   c++         positive    3136    33.13960        16.56980    8
8   c++         neutral     2008    21.21949        43.74934    8
9   c++         negative    4319    45.64092        77.17954    8
```

And I have been trying to visualize them by using ggplot2 bar chart:

```
p <-ggplot() + theme_bw() + geom_bar(aes(y=tone_percent, x=reorder(language, -pos), fill=tone), data=data, stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(data=data, aes(x = language, y = label_pos, ymax=label_pos, hjust = 0.5, label = paste0(round(tone_percent),"%")), size=4) + 
  labs(x="Language", y="Percentage of tone") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#F45E5A', '#5086FF', '#17B12B')) + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.direction="horizontal", legend.title = element_blank()) + coord_flip()
```

and it gives almost excellent result:
[image]

However, the legend shows the labels in alphabetical order, but I would like to display them in the same order as bars are drawn in the chart : Positive then Neutral then Negative

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: That's not a good dupe; that approach would change the color order of the bars as well, so they still wouldn't line up with the legend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the `guides` parameter of the `scale` functions `guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)`, which will reverse the legend order without reordering the bars. Cleaned up a bit:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = reorder(language, -pos), y = tone_percent, fill = tone)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    geom_text(aes(y = label_pos, label = paste0(round(tone_percent),"%"))) + 
    coord_flip() + 
    labs(x = "Language", y = "Percentage of tone") +
    scale_fill_manual(NULL, values=c('#F45E5A', '#5086FF', '#17B12B'), 
                      guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
          legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

[image: plot with correct legend]

Comment: That works, thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the tone variable as a factor.

`data$tone <- factor(data$tone, levels=c("positive", "neutral", "negative"))`

Comment: Thanks, but "tone" is actually the factor, I checked that: > str(data)
'data.frame': 9 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ language    : Factor w/ 8 levels "c","c#","c++",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
 $ tone        : Factor w/ 3 levels "negative","neutral",..: 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1
 $ count       : int  3460 2046 4060 3732 1832 3479 3136 2008 4319
 $ tone_percent: num  36.2 21.4 42.4 41.3 20.3 ...
 $ label_pos   : num  18.1 46.9 78.8 20.6 51.4 ...
 $ pos         : int  7 7 7 3 3 3 8 8 8

Comment: @sovo2014 You need to format it by specifying the levels to control the order. Check `levels(data$tone)`